# Update the old row and insert if new in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have add row functionality in my form while on update form i need update the old data and if any new row is added in form then a new data is insert in my db how could i do in YII.
  My controller Code is

```
if(isset($_POST['LeadTargetEducation']))
{
    $target = new LeadTargetEducation; 
    $count= count($_POST['LeadTargetEducation']);               
    $target->attributes=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'];

    //the value for the foreign key 'groupid'
    $lead_id = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
          ->select('max(id) lead')
          ->from('lead_details')
          ->queryRow();

    $val=$lead_id['lead'];
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {       
        $target->lead_id=$val;
        $target->edu_id=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['edu_id'];
        $target->country_id=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['country_id'];
        $target->universty_id=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['universty_id'];
        $target->academic_year=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['academic_year'];
        $target->sub_edu=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['sub_edu'];
        $target->course_id=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['course_id'];
        $target->req_prior_target_edu=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['req_prior_target_edu'];
        $target->add_course=$_POST['LeadTargetEducation'][$i]['add_course'];        
        $target->save();                
     }
}
```

Comment: whats `$i` ? do you have a loop or something?

Comment: instead of adding a row in the same form, you should do it in the different window on a different form

Comment: yes i have a loop in the form

Answer (score 1):

you are missing to make a **new model** each time you are trying to save an new one, do like this to prevent updating the same record:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{       
    $target = new LeadTargetEducation(); // see this line
    $target->lead_id=$val; // I issume this is not the primary key!
    .
    .        
    .
    $target->save(); // and finally save it
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for beforesave method; You can create beforesave function in your model

```
function beforeSave(){
  $tableB = new new LeadTargetEducation();
  $tableB->edu_id = $this->edu_id;
  more...

  $tableB->save();
}
```